# How to save a received file from client server with different name using Python

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I have a server which accepts a file from each of his client but I would like to save each file in ascending order like file1.txt file2.txt.. etc

My server part that accepts the file is

```
def getfile(self):
    count = count+1
    g = open('from_client'+count+'.txt','wb')

    while True:
        print('receiving data...')
        data = self.sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print('data=%s', (data))

        if not data:
            g.close()
            print('Successfully get the file')
            self.sock.close()
            break
        # write data to a file
        g.write(data)
```

How to save it each time with different filename?

Comment: What have you tried to solve that problem so far?

Comment: By adding a counter? but I am not sure if it is the proper way

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert my counter to string with str(count) and place count=0 outside my class

```
def getfile(self,count):
    count = count+1
    g = open('from_client'+str(count)+'.txt','wb')

    while True:
        print('receiving data...')
        data = self.sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print('data=%s', (data))

        if not data:
            g.close()
            print('Successfully get the file')
            self.sock.close()
            break
```